# Java: Add Place Holder on JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, prompt

Is there a way or method in which we can add placeholder in  j text field. I want to add placeholder "Enter Your Number" in field but how can I do this. I check all methods but didn't working.
Code:

```
public class Loop extends JFrame{

    private JTextField t1;

        public L(){

        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        t1=new JTextField();
        t1.setBounds(27,50,47,28);
        getContentPane().add(t1);

        setSize(400,400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);

    }

      }
```

Main:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        L object = new L();
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Text Prompt](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/11/29/text-prompt/) for a flexible solution.

You can control when prompt is displayed (always, focus gained or focus lost). You can also customize the style of the text.

Comment: could you please make code of TextPrompt place holder in my above code i'm stuck at this.

Comment: @TimAllen, its one line of code to use the `TextPrompt` with its default settings. I don't know how you are stuck. Update your showing what you tried and explain what is not working the way you want.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of which you can you inspire

```
package TinyOS;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.Document;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class PlaceholderTextField extends JTextField {

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final PlaceholderTextField tf = new PlaceholderTextField ("");
    tf.setColumns(20);
    tf.setPlaceholder("Here is a placeHolder!");
    final Font f = tf.getFont();
    tf.setFont(new Font(f.getName(), f.getStyle(), 30));
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, tf);
}

private String placeholder;

public PlaceholderTextField () {
}

public PlaceholderTextField (
    final Document pDoc,
    final String pText,
    final int pColumns)
{
    super(pDoc, pText, pColumns);
}

public PlaceholderTextField (final int pColumns) {
    super(pColumns);
}
}
```

I hope that can help you

Answer (score 1):

This code should work, it listen on first click and removes the text

```
public class Loop extends JFrame{
    private JTextField t1;
    private boolean clicked = false;
    public L(){
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        t1=new JTextField();
        t1.setText("Enter Your Number");
        t1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
                if(!clicked){
                    clicked=true;
                    t1.setText("");
                }
            }
        }
        t1.setBounds(27,50,47,28);
        getContentPane().add(t1);
        setSize(400,400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Maybe better solution exists
Note - not tested

---

**EDIT** (how the boolean `clicked` works)
when you call method `mousePressed(MouseEvent)` at the first time, the `clicked` variable is `false`, by declaration:

```
private boolean clicked = false;
```

So the `if` body is executed (because **!clicked = !false = true**)
in the `if` body, the `clicked` variable is set to true, so `if` condition will be then false: (because **!clicked = !true = false**)
This solves the problem of running code just once.

Comment: can u please tell me in simple words how boolean works on if condition

Comment: if(true){} or boolean p=true; if(p){} or if (!p){}

Comment: Don't use a null layout. Not a complete solution. What happens if the user tabs to the text field? A GUI should be designed to work whether the user uses a mouse or the keyboard. What happens if the user clicks on the field and then clicks on another field? The text is removed but never replaced.

Comment: @TinyOS if boolean p = false if(!p) then true

Comment: no !p gives false :

here is an example 
`public static void main(String[] args) {
  boolean testva=false;  
  if(testva){
   System.out.println("gives true");
  }
  if(!testva){
    System.out.println("gives false");
  }
 }`